# problem with .find() function from mongoose library nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, server

I am working with `mongoose library nodejs`.

My issue is it never executes the `task.find()` function, but always catches error. IDK the reason.
I've tried multiple ways to solve this but nothing has worked.

My code

```
const Task = mongoose.model('Task', schema) //creating table for schema
//use render to load ejs view
app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.render('todo') //to show certain page in this directory

    console.log("here")
    try{                                      
    const all = Task.find(); // Get All Data from schema
    console.log(all)
    res.send(all)
}
 catch(err){
        console.log("error occured")
     }
})
```

I tried downloading older versions of mongoose but I believe these are not compatible with the other library's.
I also tried changing it from a function to object but that also doesn't work.

Comment: `console.log(err)` try printing the actual error and check what is the actual issue.

Comment: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'MongoClient'

Comment: Solved it!  used app.use(express.json())

Comment: @Azizener the `express.json()` middleware would have absolutely no effect on the code in your question